# How to Correct Error: Can't Find Mean of List with no numbers

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to get turtles (foragers) to move based on a reporter of mean nest-scent, which should report the mean of nest-scent spread throughout the world, from a high of 200 at the nest to 120 at the opposite corners of the world. However, at the nest, the error below is triggered, and I don't understand why. Isn't a mean nest-scent a list of numbers? How do I correct this error?

``````````````````````````````````
Can't find the mean of a list with no numbers: [].
error while forager 7 running MEAN
  called by procedure MEAN-NEST-SCENT-IN-CONE

to-report mean-nest-scent-in-cone [cone-distance angle angle-width ] ; ant procedure - reports the mean amount of nest-scent in cone
  rt angle
  let p patches in-cone cone-distance angle-width
  ;ask p [ show chemical ]
  if p = nobody [report 0]
  lt angle
  report (mean [nest-scent] of p)
end
`````````````````````````````````
``````````````````````````````````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set up 'p' as a patchset but you are testing whether it is 'nobody'. The primitive for agentsets is `any?`. Try replacing:

```
if p = nobody [report 0]
lt angle
report (mean [nest-scent] of p)
```

with

```
ifelse any? p
[ lt angle
  report mean [nest-scent] of p
]
[ report 0 ]
```